# Retrieve Keys and elements of Array Firebase Database

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working with Firebase realtime database and I want to retrieve an array data:

Data:

[image]

And my function:

```
   function traerUsuarios(firebase)
{
    var ref = firebase.database().ref().child('/Usuario');
    console.log(ref)
    ref.once('value', function (snap) {
        snap.forEach(function (item) {
            var itemVal = item.val();
            console.log(itemVal);
        });
        });
}
```

But the result:

Show me object but no de for of the items

[image]

What im doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `item` in your for loop are the children of Usario. Each of these children (from your picture 056BN.., CQL.., and E4ll) have an object as their value (hence why they have a `+` next to them in the database).

So when you say `item.val()` you're getting the value of each one of those children, which is their corresponding object (The data you see when you click the `+` in the database.

Comment: With your comments , i restructure the code and works , thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @MarksCode , I fixed the function with data refs:

> ```
> function traerUsuarios(firebase) {  var key;
> var starCountRef;
> var usuarios=new Array();
> // var ref = firebase.database().ref().child('/Usuario');
> var query = firebase.database().ref("/Usuario").orderByKey();
>
> query.once("value")
>         .then(function (snapshot) {
>             snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
>                 // key will be "ada" the first time and "alan" the second time
>                 key = childSnapshot.key;
>                 starCountRef = firebase.database().ref("/Usuario/"+key);
>                 starCountRef.on('value', function (snapshot) {
>                     console.log(snapshot.val());
>                     usuarios.push([key,snapshot.val()]);
>                 });
>
>             });
>         }); }
> ```

And the result show me the values:

[image]